# Problema con nextBoolean

Tags: java, arraylist

Programar una lista utilizando la clase ArrayList. La lista tiene tres atributos: uno tipo string, uno tipo double y uno tipo boolean.

Tengo la Clase creada con sus atributos, constructor vacio, contructores, getter and setter y toString. Mi clase se llama Vehiculos.

Mi problema esta en que el método nextBoolean() te obliga a introducir true or false y yo quiero introducir s/n. He intentado hacerlo de varias formas pero no ha resultado.

```
static boolean traccion4x4;

private void rellenarCoche() {
do {
    System.out.print("Tiene tracción a las cuatro ruedas s/n. ");
    traccion4x4 = leer.nextBoolean();
} while (traccion4x4 != true || traccion4x4 != false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Cambia el `nextBoolean()` por `nextLine()`

```
static String traccion4x4;

private void rellenarCoche() {
do {
    System.out.print("Tiene tracción a las cuatro ruedas s/n. ");
    traccion4x4 = leer.nextLine();
} while (!traccion4x4.equals("s") || !traccion4x4.equals("n"));
```

Comment: Cambiar un método por otro, hace que la variable se vuelva incompatible, supongo que lo que sugieres es que cambie también el tipo de variable en el modelo.